# Apple will no longer accept submissions of new apps that use UIWebView as of April 30, 2020

Tags: ios, cordova

I've applied the config.xml updates they reccommend, but I'm still getting a reject message from Apple for using the UIWebView.  Any suggestions?

I have iOS 5.1.1 and CLI 9.0.1

cordova-background-geolocation-lt 3.0.8 "BackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-launch-review 3.1.1 "Launch Review"
cordova-plugin-background-fetch 5.5.0 "CDVBackgroundFetch"
cordova-plugin-calendar 5.1.5 "Calendar"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-cocoalumberjack 0.0.4 "CocoaLumberjack"
cordova-plugin-contacts 3.0.1 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.2.1 "Cordova WKWebView Engine"

Comment: Not to sound flippant, but maybe find a replacement for this thing called Cordova? On a much more serious note, a few thoughts. (1) I actually wanted to start with something else, but - **iOS 5.1.1**? You're about 8 years out of date. (2) My original point was using third party code. Be aware that it isn't an iOS issue, as it's been well-known that `UIWebView` has been deprecated for years. Maybe you need to contact the third party? (3) Please note that Apple will no longer accept *submissions*. Nobody said that Apple won't allow your app **as is** to stay in the App Store. (iOS 5.1.1?)

Comment: That iOS5.1.1 is the cordova platform version that supports 13.x  :o)  I was able to get by it, there was some references in readme files that had the text UIWebView in it.  I just deleted them.

Comment: It's hard to replace when you have an investment, you just can't rewrite everything unless you have unlimited money.

Comment: I agree about investments - both time and money. Glad you were able to find out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get by it, there was some references in readme files that had the text UIWebView in it. I just deleted them.